# CTMLoader does not correctly assign the instanceof the geometry

Tags: three.js, instanceof

if I modify the sample webgl_loader_ctm.html and in the routine callbackModel() add these lines of code:

```
     if (geometry instanceof THREE.Object3D) alert("THREE.Object3D");
else if (geometry instanceof THREE.Geometry) alert("THREE.Geometry");
else alert("Unknown instanceof geometry");
```

I was expecting the second alert to be activated but instead I got the third. As my code depends on the instanceof to be correct, does anybody know what do I have to change in the loader in order to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main loading methods built into CTMLoader: Depending on the useBuffers parameter, it creates BufferGeometry or Geometry. You might want to first check against BufferGeometry (which is not a subclass of Geometry) too, or set the useBuffers parameter to false (I'm not familiar with CTM, so I don't know if the file formats are different for buffered vs normal).

Anyway, Three.js handling of classes can be a bit hard to keep track of, and some related classes may not share a parent class. You may or may not agree, but I would maybe do the instanceof checking ["if it looks like a duck, it is a duck"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) -style. So checking for some property that only exists in Object3D or similar objects:

```
if (geometry.lookAt) {
  alert("Looks like Object3D, I know what to do with this");
} else if (geometry.vertices) {
  alert("Looks like Geometry with some vertices, I know what to do with this");
} else {
  alert("I dont know how to handle this object");
}
```